# Different Timer for each item in List on ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a List of actions that need to be performed by company representatives and i like to open a timer if it is on edit for X minutes.
and all 10 minutes i like the page to be refreshed.

the problem is that many company agent can access and edit those action.
so i like just colored the item on my view, but if the agent "sleepee" for this X minutes - the underProcess field reset to false;

So I start with adding to my model a field who tell me that this Action are "UnderProcess" (I love CodeFirst :) And I add to the ViewModel a static dictionary an on edit i get thare and add a row with kay-actionID and DateTime of edit.
After that in my view on the foreach if item.UnderProcess the style=color:red ..
Course after edit i remove from dictionary and change the bool flag.

But that not working - it stay red after this X minutes,
I think that the problem is on this static dictionary because when i debug it is always empty.

Hare My ViewModel:

```
public class AgentActionViewModel
{
    public SupplierAction Action { get; set; }
    public List<SupplierAction> Actions { get; set; }//= new List<SupplierAction>();

    public static Dictionary<int, DateTime> UnderProcessFrom;
    public static AgentActionViewModel()
    {
        UnderProcessFrom = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();
    }
}
```

The Controller:

Index

```
[SupplierAuthorization]
public ActionResult AgentAction(..)
{
     Response.AddHeader("Refresh", (MINUTES*60).ToString());

     List<SupplierAction> actions = db.SupplierActions.ToList();            
     bool flag = false;
     var collection = AgentActionViewModel.UnderProcessFrom.Keys;
     foreach (var aId in collection)
     {
        if (AgentActionViewModel.UnderProcessFrom[aId].AddMinutes(MINUTES) <= DateTime.Now)
        {
           AgentActionViewModel.UnderProcessFrom.Remove(aId);
           var action = actions.Find(a=>a.SupplierActionID == aId);
           action.UnderProcess = false;
           db.Entry(action).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
     }

     if(flag)
        db.SaveChanges();

          ...

        var vm = new AgentActionViewModel();
        vm.Actions = actions.OrderByDescending(d => d.RequestDate).ToList();
        return View(vm);
    }
```

GET Edit:

```
    [SupplierAuthorization]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = -1)
    {
        try
        {
            ...
            if (!a.UnderProcess)
            {
                a.UnderProcess = true;
                db.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                AgentActionViewModel.UnderProcessFrom.Add(id, DateTime.Now);
            }
            ...
        }        
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ....
            if (a.UnderProcess)
            {
                a.UnderProcess = false;
                db.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                AgentActionViewModel.UnderProcessFrom.Remove(id);
            }
            .....
        }
    ...
    }
```

Post Edit :

```
.....
if (vm.Action.UnderProcess)
{
   vm.Action.UnderProcess = false;
   AgentActionViewModel.UnderProcessFrom.Remove(vm.ActionID);
}
.....
```

My View :

```
@model oCc.IPToGo.ViewModel.AgentActionViewModel
....
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Actions)
        {
            <tr style="@(item.UnderProcess ? "color:red" : "")">
                <td>
          .....
```

10x an sorry for my bad English =)

Comment: What do you mean by "open a timer"?

Comment: @PeterRitchie, That is when the representative came to editing, I mean he get the edit page,I add the ActionID on the dictionary and the time when he began to edit, and all refresh  I check how match time passed, like you can see in the "get edit"- controller ActionResult and on "Index"

Answer (score 1):

Using static memory as a repository in a web application is a bad idea, even if the repository is for short term.

The main reason is that a memory repository cannot be scaled - if you run the server in a multi-process topography, or a multi-machine topography - the memory is not shared, do your timers will not be shared either.

Also, when the server is restarted - the memory is gone with it, and you lose information.

I suggest you use a more scallable repository, maybe `memcached` if you don't it to be part of your database.

At the very least, it would make it easier to debug your problem.

Comment: 10x @Uri, one more, Do you think that if I just write on an hidden input the time and allways I check if the eimespan is less then 10 min if so to color, is the better way or the DB way?

Comment: It is really dependent on your use-case - is this a client state or a server state? What should happen if the user never posts the form? What happens if another user changes an item's state? If you can answer those questions with a client solution - go ahead and implement it